# Potential danger of infection through downloading malware?

Tags: malware, virus, macos

Recently I was on Nox Player's website checking out their Android emulator. I did some googling and came to the conclusion that it was bundled with tons of malware and as a result didn't install it.

In the process, I accidentally clicked on the Windows 10 download link which began to download an .exe file. I immediately cancelled the download and cleared Chrome's cache.

Is it possible to be infected by the malware if you simply downloaded 2 MB of 150MB? For reference, I am using macOS so it isn't even compatible with .exe programs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, no. If you didn't execute anything, the odds are approaching 0 (especially since it wasn't a MacOS executable).

Comment: That's what my thought was. It would have have to be a zero day exploit written for Mac even though the file was meant for Windows. Very unlikely to affect anyone so why would a hacker even bother.